# Variables get cleared in incoming call in android

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

In my application there is a scenario in which all the variables in the app get cleared when I get incoming call while using my app. I think the Android OsS is collecting the garbage to make free space.

But this makes my app working weird. There are nearly 30 static variables used in my app which are all get cleared. Any suggestion to not get cleared.

Thanks.

Comment: lack of any code makes your question really hopeless. What answer you expect?

Comment: Static variables do not get cleared by the GC unless you change them to null. If your app uses a lot of memory, maybe Android is force closing it in the background when the call comes in? But we need to see some code to understand.

Comment: Save the data you actually need to persistent storage. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thnaks! I appreciate your quick response. In my app I using state_id as a identifier which stores a integer value. For example while using my app state_id = 1431; after getting a call it get cleared and variable becomes null state_id = null. I don't want to clear my values in variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems like this occur, if you do not correctly implement the activity life cycle. In particular you have to override `onSaveInstanceState()` if you have data that should be preserved when your activity is stopped.

Please have a look at the official [activity guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) for more details.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid our app from getting stopped when other app comes front?

Comment: You could probably make it less likely (not sure about it) but you should not. It is the responsibility of the OS to manage the device resources (memory, CPU, ...).